# combine data if same value php, html table, codeigniter 3

Tags: codeigniter

I will create a table with data in and out of goods in 1 month,i use codeigniter 3,
i got data by join sql.
and the result is:

[image: array from sql]

and i implement to html table with:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-inverse table-responsive">
    <thead class="thead-inverse">
      <tr>
        <th rowspan="3">Nama barang</th>
        <th colspan="<?= $number * 2 ?>">Bulan <?php echo $dt->format("m"); ?></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= $number; $i++) { ?>

          <th colspan="2"> <?php echo $i ?></th>
        <?php } ?>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= $number; $i++) { ?>
          <td>in</td>
          <td>out</td>
        <?php } ?>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php foreach ($barang_keluar as $barang_keluar) {
        $day = date_create($barang_keluar['tanggal_keluar']);
      ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?= $barang_keluar['barang'] ?></td>
          <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= $number * 2; $i++) { ?>
            <?php $tanggal = $day->format('d');
            if ($i == $tanggal * 2 - 1) { ?>
              <td style="text-align: center; background-color: red; color: white;"><?= $barang_keluar['masuk'] ?></td>
              <?php if ($i == $tanggal * 2 - 1) { ?>
                <td style="text-align: center; background-color: violet; color: white;"><?= $barang_keluar['keluar'] ?></td>
              <?php   } else { ?>
                <td></td>
              <?php } ?>
            <?php } else { ?>
              <td></td>
            <?php }
            ?>
          <?php } ?>
        </tr>
      <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

and i have the value like:
[image]

the question is:
how to make the "pulpen" data is one row
like:
[image]

Comment: Don't loop tr for number of $barang_keluar, loop td for number of days in that month. Then check if that month is present in data to show n that column. Looping and indexing the data of $barang_keluar will make it easier.

Comment: Also you should not loop with same name "foreach ($barang_keluar as $barang_keluar)"

Comment: how about looping and indexing data, I don't understand